# is mousedown events inherently slower than mouseup events?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fairly chunky page, which lots of clickable elements, which I'm testing on a relatively slow computer (~1GHz processor). Part of the page is an on-screen keyboard as part of the page. I use jQuery with event delegation for all the buttons, and react to either mousedown or mouseup events (one or the other, not both at once). When testing both cases, it seems that mouseup events are slower and less reliable (sometimes the button press is missed, or the screen hangs slightly before responding) than mousedown. This is especially the case if hitting lots of buttons in rapid succession.

Is there any reason mousedown should be inherently faster/better than mouseup? Would event delegation impact on this? For user experience I'm favouring mouseup events, so I'd like to know if there is anything I can do to improve the mouseup reliability.

Comment: Are you having the same issue with different browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classic **user  click** triggers `mousedown` and `mouseup`.
The time between the two is usually somewhere **~50ms**.
 In that short period of time the browser might be busy due to processes fired by `mousedown` and **event bubbling and propagation**, specially if you bound too much handlers far up in the DOM tree like to `document` or `"html, body"`. **Avoid that**.

Also, `mouseup` might end up being *never registered*.
If some processes are taking too much time  or you're simply too fast with your mouse, the `mouseup` might not be over the *target element* at the time it's triggered, therefore **never firing that event**.